# How to implement a destroy confirmation form with simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud, simple-form

I'm using Ruby on Rails 4 with simple_form. On my delete page, I would like to display a form confirming the user's decision to destroy the resource in question. Here is the code I am using:

```
<h2>Delete Page</h2>
<p>Are you sure you want to delete <%= @journalEntry.title %></p>

<%= simple_form_for(@journalEntry, :action => 'destroy') do |f| %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

However, this is getting processed by the `update` action instead (my server console shows that it is being sent as a PATCH request).

I also tried amending that code to the following, but with the same result:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@journalEntry, :url => {:action => 'destroy', :id => @journalEntry.id}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you tried `f.button :submit, :onclick => "return confirm('Are you sure?')` ? and you need to include `:method => :delete` to form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `:method => :delete` option with `simple_form_for` :

```
<%= simple_form_for(@journalEntry, :method => :delete) %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks (and thanks to @Talgat as well). I'm new to using restful routes, but this solution makes sense to me now.